# How to limit DB Connections in massive scale Java App

Tags: java, postgresql, oracle11g, java-ee-6, apache-commons-dbcp

I have a Java app with more than 100 servers. Currently each server opens up connections to 7 database schemas in a relational databases (logging, this, that, the other). All schemas connect to the same DB cluster, but its all effectively one database instance.

The server managed connection pools open up a handfull of connections (1 - 5) on each database schema per instance, then double that on a redundant pool. So each server open up a minimum of 30 database connections and can grow to a maximum of several hundred per server, and again, there are more than 100 servers.

All in all, the minimum number of database connections used are 3000, and this can grow to ludricous.

Obviously this is just plain wrong. The database cluster can only effeciently handle X concurrent requests and any number of requests > X introduces unnecessary contention and slows the whole lot down. (X is unknown, but it is way smaller than the 3000 minimum concurrent connections).

I want to lower the total connections used by implementing the following strategy:

1. Connect to one schema only (Application-X), have 6 connections per pool maximum.
2. Write a layer above the pool that will switch to the schema I want. The getConnection(forSchema) function will take a parameter for the target schema (eg. logging), will get a connection that could last be pointing to any schema, and issue a schema switch SQL statement (set search_path to 'target_schema').

Please do not comment on whether this approach is right or wrong. Because 'it depends' needs to be considered, such comments will not add value.

My question is whether there is a DB pool implementation out there that already does this - allows me to have one set of connections and automatically places me at the right schema, or better yet - tracks whether a pooled connection is available for your target schema before making a decision to go ahead and switch the schema (saves a DB round trip).

I would also like to hear from anyone else who has a similar issue (real-world experience) if you solved it in a different way.

Comment: Is your "app" a website? When you say the number of connections can grow, is it due to increased website traffic?

Comment: Yes this is a web site. By 'server' I mean Java App Server, as in WebLogic, Tomcat, JBosss.

Answer (score 2):

Having learned the hard way myself, the best way to stabilize the number of database connections between a web application and a database is to put a reverse proxy in front of the web application.

Here's why it works:

A slow part of a web request can be returning the data to the client. If there's a lot of data  or the user is on a slow connection, the connection can remain open to the web server where the data dribbles out to the client slowly. Meanwhile, the application server continues to hold a database connection open to the backend server. While the database connection may only needed for a fraction of the transaction, it's tied up until client disconnects from the application server.

Now, consider what happens when a reverse proxy is added in front of the app server. When the app server has a response prepared, it can quickly reply back to the reverse proxy in front of it, and free up the database connection behind it. The reverse proxy can then handle slowly dribbling out responses to uses, without keeping a related database connection tied up.

Before I made this architectural change, there were a number of traffic spikes that resulted in death spirals: the database handle usage would spike to exhaustion, and things would go downhill from there.

After the change, the number of the database handles required was both far less and far more stable.

If a reverse proxy is not already part of your architecture, I recommend it as a first step to control the number of database connections you require.

Comment: what excellent insight! In our environment data is read into a local session cache and transactions and connections are released immediately under direct control. The connections are not linked in any way to the request response cycle. I think that your suggestion will assist me however to lower concurrency in servers themselves! +1